# Laravel, use middleware to find Domain, then get Website row using Domain row.

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use some middleware to get a row from a `website` table, this row is referenced within my `domains` table.

This is my middleware so far:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use App\Domains;
    use Closure;

    class Domain
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {

            $domainRow = Domains::where([ 'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ])->first();

            dd($domainRow->website);

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

And here is my `Domains` model, which works fine except the **hasOne** part:

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Domains extends Model
    {

        public function website()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Website');
        }

    }
```

The **hasOne** part is generating the below query:

> Unknown column 'websites.domains_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `websites` where `websites`.`domains_id` = 2 and `websites`.`domains_id` is not null limit 1)

However the query I need it to make is:

> SELECT * FROM websites WHERE id = 1

Where `1` is from the `website_id` column within the Domains table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change website method  to:

```
public function website() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Website');
}
```

Comment: The inverse relationship to hasOne is belongsTo

Comment: Damn, I should of really seen this! Thanks, spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses a self "inteligent" system to detect foreign keys from local key. The local key would be the `website_id` in the Domain's model. And the foreign key is `id` located in website's model definition.
Try to change the relationship to:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Website', 'website_id', 'id');
```

This way you are enforcing your own variables, disabling self "inteligence" applied by laravel.
More info: [Laravel One to One relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: That is going to force it to look for the "website_id" on the websites table matching the "id" on the domains table.